# Oracle 12c Installer Showing unknown Language

Tags: java-8, oracle12c

[image: When running the Oracle setup, it shows unrecognizable language.]

I've referred to below document for resolution but unable to succeed.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b16227/oui9_internalization.htm#OUICG009

Environment:
AWS t2.2xlarge instance
OS- Windows Server 2016

Region and Language Settings are also okay.

What to do to resolve this?

Comment: You may have better luck with support forums dedicated to those products.

Comment: I hope, I’m not offending any native speaker of an exotic language, but to me, it looks more like garbage than an actual “unknown language”. Perhaps, the language data just got corrupted. But how does that relate to “[java-8]”? Just because both products are from Oracle?

Comment: It's related to Java because as according to Orcale docs: "Oracle Universal Installer runs in the language of the operating system. Oracle Universal Installer uses the language that Java detects, the system locale value, and sets that to the default language." https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b16227/oui9_internalization.htm#OUICG009

Comment: what are the actual steps that you followed to install oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. I installed xorg-x11-fonts and everything is OK now.

Answer (score 0):

It is a font issue. I had the same one and tried to install xorg-x11-fonts and the package was not available. 
Download

yum groupinstall "X Window System"

This will install pretty much everything you need with X11 including fonts.